# Lagging recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create app with tab layout and in one of tabs I want to create 2 recyclerviews but only 1 will be shown on screen at once. Data for 1 recyclerview is downloaded from Web on the app start and data for second is downlaoded after clicking button on screen. When data for second recyclerView is downloaded, recyclerView is shown, but it's laggy. When I hide the second recyclerView (the one downlaoded with button click) and then show it again without downlaoding data it's working normally - no lags at all. 
There is a lot of code in this activity, so I will add only a few lines, if more will be required I will add more. 
Second RecyclerView's adapter :

```
private static class CommentsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        public CommentsAdapter() {}

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }

        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView commentTitle;
            public TextView commentText;
            public TextView deleteComment;
            public TextView commentRating;
            public ImageView upVote;
            public ImageView downVote;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                ...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comment, parent, false);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            ... (a lot of code, but it's not the reason why recycler view is laggy)
            });
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return titles.length;
        }
    }
```

For Editing Rating and Deleting Comments I'm using volley and structures same like this doesn't lag anything else so I guess it's not the problem. 
Code for downloading comments :

```
private void ReadComments() {

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait, loading comments...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.show();
        Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        params.put("tag", tag + "");
        CustomJsonRequest request = new CustomJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_get_comments, params,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        try {
                            jsonParser = response.toString();
                            Log.d("Comments ", response.toString());
                            news = response.getJSONArray("comments");
                            if (!response.toString().contains("No products found")) {
                                titles = new String[news.length()];
                                descs = new String[news.length()];
                                ratings = new int[news.length()];
                                pids = new int[news.length()];
                                users = new String[news.length()];

                                for (int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject c = news.getJSONObject(i);
                                    titles[i] = c.getString("title");
                                    descs[i] = c.getString("desc");
                                    ratings[i] = c.getInt("rating");
                                    pids[i] = c.getInt("pid");
                                    users[i] = c.getString("user");
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (titles != null) {
                            if (titles.length == 0) {
                                noComments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            } else {
                                CommentsAdapter commentsAdapter = new CommentsAdapter();
                                commentsView.setAdapter(commentsAdapter);
                            }
                        } else {
                            noComments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                        pDialog.hide();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
```

And that's all what is doing anything with this recyclerView. 
Whole code you can find on my GitHub : https://github.com/LisSkis/HowItTastes 
Files with RecyclerViews are : HomeContent.java, recycler_view.xml

Answer (score 2):

Set this to your recyclerView:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```